# Django jinja2 syntax confusing

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

```
 {% extends "personal/home.html"%}
 { % block content%}
 (% include 'personal/includes/help.html' %)
 (% endblock %)
```

The line 4 correct syntax would be `{% endblock %}`.
However I get the

> forgot to register tag?

`TemplateSyntaxError`.

EDIT: I solved the issue using (`% endblock %`) instead of curls. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'd imagine its because your [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#include) is also using `(` instead of `{`

Comment: Well it won't work, I would get an error "Error during template rendering" and "Invalid block tag on line 4: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

I checked putting curls instead of brackets both third and last line. @Sayse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax errors.

There is an extra space at the start of the `block` tag, so the open tag is not being recognised. This means that Django will complain when it gets to the end tag.

You are also using `()` instead of `{}` in several tags.

(Note, this appears to be Django template language, not Jinja2.)

Comment: Silly mistake of mine, Thanks a lot!! @Daniel